# How to construct Elasticsearch query with Go?

Tags: elasticsearch, go, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-query

I'm using olivere's Elasticsearch library for Go - https://github.com/olivere/elastic

I'm not able to properly construct the search query, it keeps returning 0 hits.

```
termQuery := elasticClient.NewTermQuery("hash", "hashedID")
fmt.Println(termQuery)
searchResult, err := qs.client.Search().Index("someIndex").
    Type("node").
    Query(termQuery).
    Pretty(true).
    Do(ctx)
if err != nil {
    return nil
}
```

`searchResult.Hits.TotalHits` gives 0 hits even though there is data. 
The data is in an Elasticsearch server running on my local machine which I can see if I run a REST API call:

```
{
   "_index": "someIndex",
   "_type": "node",
   "_id": "hashedID",
   "_score": 1,
   "_source": {
   "node": "test",
   "hash": "hashedID",
   "active": true
}
```

How can I fix my Search query?

Comment: Are you sure returning `nil` for for condition `err != nil` is a good idea? I think there might be errors you can't see. You could use `panic(err)` to print the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Your go script is just fine and it works. The problem is with the query itself. This is what you are executing against elasticsearch. Try it directly against elasticsearch (via Sense, Kibana or similar tool) and check if it returns what you expect:

```
POST someIndex/node/_search
{
    "query": {
        "term": {
           "hash": "hashedID"
        }
    }
}
```

#### Solution:

I suspect that hash is of type `text` (using elasticsearch 5). Then you need to query for `hash.keyword` on a term query instead.

Comment: Was this helpful or are you stuck on something else?